# Spatie/Ray package within a wordpress plugin

Tags: ddev

I'm having issues getting the spatie/ray package up and running within a ddev wordpress site.

I am currently working on a plugin, and have spatie/ray included with composer as a dev dependency.
The plugin is sitting at /Users/{user_name}/Clients/{client_name}/Sites/{site_name}/wp-content/plugins/{plugin_name}

In the folder above i have a 'ray.php' file with ray config in it as per the ray documentation at https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/environment-specific-configuration/docker

ie.

```
return [
'host' => 'host.docker.internal',
'port' => 23517,
'remote_path' => '/var/www/html',
'local_path' => '/Users/{user_name}/Clients/{client_name}/Sites/{site_name}' // path to wp folder
]
```

I have also added 127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal to my etc/hosts file and confirmed that the ray application is listening on port 23517.

Any ideas on what part of the setup I am missing or not understanding? Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about ray... You do not need to add host.docker.internal anywhere; DDEV or Docker will provide that for you inside teh container. But I think the `remote_path` is probably the /Users/... and the `local_path` is probably /var/www/html. You'll have to understand where your ray.php is executing. If it's inside the container, then these are the things you need. Come on over to Discord to discuss more, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k